# Cheapest path in a matrix

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, algorithms

Consider an $m \times n$ matrix and I want to find the cheapest path from $a_{1,1}$ to $a_{m,n}$, given **one can only move right or down**.

Is there any algorithm to calculate this? What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Edit: Matrix entries are considered to be the cost of one step.

For eg: the following matrix has the cheapest cost of $(10+2+2+2+3) = 19$

\begin{bmatrix}
10 & 5 & 6 \\    
2  & 4 & 7 \\
2  & 2 & 3
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: Are the matrix entries considered as costs to go one step? Or do the entries represent costs in some way?

Comment: This depends on what you consider to be cheap.

Comment: Matrix entries are considered as costs of one step.

Comment: You shall write it in your question.

Comment: If matrix entries are one step costs, then what is $a_{2,5}$ ? [since one can't go from 2 to 5 in one step]

Comment: [A* algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)

Comment: There are many ways to reach a<sub>25</sub>, so every matrix entires until you reach a<sub>25</sub> is the cost

Comment: @coffeemath I think he means not as a graph theory cost matrix but to take a step from $a_{24}$ or $a_{15}$ to $a_{25}$ has the cost which is in the element $a_{25}$, but I am not sure.

Comment: @coffeemath I have added an example to make it clear.

Comment: Maybe one can use Dynamic programming. Let $D(i,j)$ be a minimal cost from $a_{11}$ to $a_{ij}$, and try to find a recurrence relation of $D(i, j)$.

Comment: It's problem 81 from the Project Euler (https://projecteuler.net)

Comment: Direct link for the comment above: https://projecteuler.net/problem=81

Comment: ...This guy has solutions in Java, Python etc: https://www.nayuki.io/page/project-euler-solutions

Answer (score 1):

One method is **Dijkstra's_algorithm** under:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming

I think you can use smallest cost instead of shortest path in your example.

> Dijkstra's algorithm for the shortest path problem
>
> From a dynamic programming point of view, Dijkstra's algorithm for the shortest path problem is a successive approximation scheme that solves the dynamic programming functional equation for the shortest path problem by the Reaching method.[6][7][8]
>
> In fact, Dijkstra's explanation of the logic behind the algorithm,[9] namely
>
> Problem 2. Find the path of minimum total length between two given nodes P and Q.
>
> > We use the fact that, if R is a node on the minimal path from P to Q, knowledge of the latter implies the knowledge of the minimal path from P to R.
>
> is a paraphrasing of Bellman's famous Principle of Optimality in the context of the shortest path problem.